# Deleting parent node with child value

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am struggling to overcome to issue I have. I am trying to delete a parent node/key given I find the correct child value.

[My database is structure liked this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8j0X.png)

I am querying my database by a certain value, `objectID`, as it will match the `postID` which is passed through the parameters. The `objectID` value is removed. However, I am struggling to remove the key in which it falls under.

I have had mixed results so far:

I can either remove the `objectID` value using this code:

`refSnap?.ref.child("objectID").child(postID).removeValue()`

Of I can remove the whole `notifications` node/directory, using this:

`refSnap?.ref.child("objectID").queryEqual(toValue: postID).ref.removeValue()`

`refSnap?.key` gives me all the keys/nodes under the `notifications` node.

I cannot access the key which the `objectID` and all other information is stored under as it is `.childByAutoId`. Can anyone possibly help me as to how I can sort this issue?

Comment: Can you give some more context as to what each of them represents in your app? e.g 1st child is the userID, 2nd child(starting with LFE...) is notificationID, that "key" that you refer to what is it?

Comment: it appears you are concatenating uid's with a `-` to enable lookup/queries? I think you might not have a solid db architecture / pattern. Have a look at [Structure Your Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data)

Comment: @Do2 this key `-LFEzrrqsgsoLeg7AGAj` is what I am referring to. The expnaded key. I have the objectID I have ran a query where it does in fact equal whatever value is passed through the parameters. Now given this information, I would like to remove/delete the `-LFEzrrqsgsoLeg7AGAj` key/node.

Comment: There is a very simple solution but you need to include your Firebase structure as *text* and also please include the code with what you've tried so far. Including one liners doesn't help as we don't know what refSnap is or how it was populated. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Images and Links are Evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: If you are querying for a node that contains an objectID then you must know the path that you want to query, right? So then your query returns a snapshot of the specific node that contains the objectID, you get it's key and then delete it. i.e.   pathWeQueriedRef.child(key).removeValue.  If you can update your question with the code that performs the query, I will post an answer with code to delete the node you want deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using `childByAutoId` and you can't "tie" these random alphanumerics to something(in this case the post).

The structure that i would set is this:

```
-notifications

  --uid //notifications for user
      --- userAid+userBid //follow notification, if they unfollow you already now which one it is and you can go and delete it
      ---commentNotificationID // you give this notification the same Id that the comment has, so if the user deletes the comment you use that id to delete the notification as well.
```

Comment: The key that consists of concatenation is merely another type of notification that works fine. The issue is the key/parent that is expanded. I am trying to remove this node/child as a whole given if the condition is met (my code function). In my code right now, the `objectID` does match the `postID` that is passed through the parameters. Now I just wish to delete the key `-LFEzrrqsgsoLeg7AGAj`

Comment: I get that, when i say key i refer to the `-LFEzrrqsgsoLeg7AGAj`. But you still have not answered my question what does every node under notification represent?? Clearly the childByAutoID doesnt work for you and you need to choose a different naming convention or delete it all together but if i dont know what each child represents i cant advise you.

Comment: Every node under notification represents a different type of notification. The node that has concetenation is a follow notification. Which is generated if a person follows a person and is also remove is they decide to unfollow. The logic works flawlessly. I am trying to remove the notification(s) for comments as this will try and populate this information in the table view controller where this function is called but as you can image it crashes, Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Thank you for helping me. Apologies for me being an idiot. Thank you ever so much. I really really appreciate it. Have a good day kind sir.

Comment: Pleasure, just for future reference the more info you provide the easier and faster you make it for someone to help you...

Comment: @iSwift Hate to say it but this answer contains incorrect information and you are going through an unneeded restructuring of your database. You can easily obtain the parent node or even a parents parent node and just delete the node in question.

Comment: @Jay Yeah receiving the whole child node, iterating through it to find the key and then  delete the key it is better than knowing what to delete straight away, since when?! Post an answer with your approach but slamming my answer without any constructive criticism(and judging by your comment on the question offering an approach lot less efficient) is inappropriate! Get of my back and my answers for that matter-not the first time you are doing this! Now care to delete your silly comment before i flag it?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I simply pointed out that this answer contains incorrect info. You can certainly leverage and use a key created with .childByAutoId to tie posts, users and other information together. At no point did I suggest any kind of iteration technique so I don't really know what that means. It's important the OP doesn't go off in a direction that's going to create a lot of extra work for them and may actually cause them to be coded into a corner. Nobody is on your back and we appreciate the effort to post an answer. My solution just takes a few lines of code which is efficient.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answer provides some insight with an alternate and workable structure, the ability to delete a node based on a child is fairly straightforward and directly addresses the question without changing the structure.

(note that the structure may need to be changed anyway but for this exercise, we'll use it as is.)

Given a structure suggested in the question:

```
notification
   "rtupy..." //childByAutoId
      "-LFEMjAcny..." // childByAutoId
      "-LFEzrrq..."  // childByAutoId
          from: "aw,sdasdad"
          objectID: "-LFEMjAcn...."
          timestamp: 15292
          type: "comment"
```

Suppose you want to delete the node "-LFEzrrq..." as shown in your screenshot. That node contains the child objectID: "-LFEMjAcn...."

To delete the node you need query for the node that contains the objectID you want which, according to the question, is working and returning the correct child.

Use the returned snapshot to obtain it's parent key, and get the path to that node and delete it. Note that we don't know what process or code the OP used to obtain the node they want to delete - perhaps it was from another query and the node reference was passed in or some other means.

```
let queryRef = //unknown how, but build the query for objectID = "-LFEMjAcny...."
queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let key = snapshot.key //this is the parent key of the objectID node i.e. -LFEMzrrq..."
    let parentRef = snapshot.ref.parent! //this is the path to that parent
    let refToDelete = parentRef.child(key) //add the parent key to the path: -LFEzrrq
    refToDelete.removeValue() //delete it
})
```

As you can see, regardless of the parent nodes' key, or how deep it is, this code will delete the node found in the query.

The key names do not matter so using .childByAutoId as references to tie your nodes together is safe and generally best practice as disassociating node keys from the data they contain makes your structure highly expandable.

Comment: Read the author's question and their comments on my answer and tell me how can you build the `queryRef`? "If you are querying for a node that contains an objectID then you must know the path that you want to query, right? " You are assuming that the author hasn't made a mistake, look at the code and the database and tell me how would you be able to get the path...

Comment: @Do2 I agree with you. It's not the best structure as presented but it may be needed for this use case. The author states *I am trying to delete a parent node/key given I find the correct child value* So we have to work with the assumption that the author finds the node with the correct child value. However, there are a number of other ways that would happen. If a parent node is retrieved with a query (the key being unknown and variable depending on the query) and then that node needs to be queried.

Comment: I recently saw a structure where the key to the first child item was then used to query for a subsequent node in the list; I believe it was a real time data stream from a scientific instrument. This structure is similar; the *notification* node would be read by value and the key to the first child node would be the node to be queried for any child nodes that contain the given objectId. since we don't know the first node key, or the child key that contains the objectID we are looking for, the code in my answer 'unravels' the path so the node can be deleted. Keep in mind there are other options.

Comment: There may be another clue in that the first child node within the first child node starts with the objectID the user is querying for. Perhaps a coincidence but that would also be a situation where you've got a known_node/variable_key_a/variable_key_b/objectID: variable_key_a

Comment: I assumed that the author did not make a mistake until proven(I don’t think I am mistaken) otherwise, I couldn’t figure out how would be possible to get to that node directly that’s why I asked you if you could get it. And if we knew the id in question we would t need any of our suggestions..I am not saying that there aren’t other options, all I am saying is with your suggestion the further you can go is to “rtup...” then you are going to have to  download all the children in your snapshot and find what you are looking for, now imagine if you had 100-1000 notifs,how efficient would that be?

Comment: Also you said that my answer contained incorrect info, what would that be? Genuinely asking...

Comment: @Do2 There is no downloading huge snapshots or any kind of iteration involved in my answer. It is simply showing that given a child node with an unknown parent and/or depth of parents, you can through code, calculate it's parent, or it's parent parent etc. For the OP they state they have an existing child node but don't know how to *delete the parent that contains that child* and that's exactly what the code does. The structure and thought process in your answer is not wrong. The issue is *childByAutoId and you can't "tie" these random alphanumerics to something* which is not correct.

Comment: Could you please use the the keys from the op’s screenshot to write your ‘queryRef’? As I can’t see how you could possibly go until the “LFEzrr...” .